# Monotonicity of a function

Tags: analysis, functions

Can you guys help me with this question?

For which $t \ne 2$ is the function $$f(x) = \frac{(x+t)}{(x-t)}$$ strictly monotonically decreasing in $x_0 = 2$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @Arber Kryeziu : what does "stricly monotonically decreasing in $x_0 = 2$" mean?  It doesn't really mean anything for a function to be decreasing at one point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

$$f(x)=1+\frac{2t}{x-t}\implies f'(x)=-\frac{2t}{(x-t)^2}<0\iff t>0\;\ldots$$